# I want to save all Button values in array using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 buttons with the same name and different values, I want when i click on any button, it's getting value and save in array. e.g [1,2].

here's my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const UserDetails = ({ navigation }) => {
  // Here i make a state
  const [selecthostingOption, setselecthostingOption] = useState([]);
  const hostingChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setselecthostingOption(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={hostingChange} name="selecthostingOption" value="1">
        Value 1
      </button>
      <button onClick={hostingChange} name="selecthostingOption" value="2">
        Value 2
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
export default UserDetails;
```

I have attached the image.

[image]

Comment: as you said it's getting value and you're also storing it, so what's the problem here ?
also in diagram `{1,2,3}` is object not array

Comment: right now, it's not saved in array. It's console me single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the set function like so `setselecthostingOption(e.target.value)`, you're not pushing the value into the array but you're replacing the array with whatever value is assigned to `e.target.value`.

For you to be able to push into your state, you'll need to give it the new array with your value in it.

```
setselecthostingOption(prevState => [
  ...prevState,
  newValue
])
```

## How it can be used:

```
const onClick = (ev) => {
  const value = ev.target.value
  setter(prevState => [
    ...prevState,
    value
  ])
}

<button onClick={onClick} value="1">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: when  i click button on second time, it's show me error
Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Answer updated with how you could use the theory behind the original version

Comment: when i console , it's show me empty array. Also it's console me previous state value not current.

Comment: Now it's working thank you. It's due to console right after the setstate.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, Heres one possible solution:

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    const UserDetails = ({ navigation }) => {
      // Here i make a state
      const [selecthostingOption, setselecthostingOption] = useState([]);
      const hostingChange = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.value);
        setselecthostingOption([...selecthostingOption, e.target.value]);
      };

//setState isn't synchronous, so if you want to do something after the state //has changed, you need to use **useEffect**
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(selecthostingOption)
      }, [selecthostingOption]);



     return (
        <>
          <button onClick={hostingChange} name="selecthostingOption" value="1">
            Value 1
          </button>
          <button onClick={hostingChange} name="selecthostingOption" value="2">
            Value 2
          </button>
        </>
      );
    };
    export default UserDetails;
```

Preview on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-engelbart-pjfpv

you might wanna use `useEffect` to see if the state has updated properly on your code.

Comment: It's working but when i click first time, the array show me empty.

Comment: How do you know that the array is empty?

Comment: when i console the selecthostingOption the value

Comment: That's not the right way to get the value after running `setState`, I am updating my codesandbox.